# Is it possible to continue numbering after inserting an image in Ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using the classic version of ckeditor, and want to continue numbering after inserting an image. Let's say the editor content is:

```
1. AAAA
2. BBBB
3. CCCC
4. DDDD
```

If I insert an image in the second bullet, the numeration changes to:

```
1. AAAA
2. BBBB
   <image>
1. CCCC
2. DDDD
```

Is it possible to continue it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason list gets broken in two (it should not take place IMHO) when you insert an image, you can use [List Style](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/liststyle) plugin to set then start number to 3 for the second list.

This plugin is available only in Full package by default but you can add it manually or using [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder) (which will take care of extra dependencies the plugin may have)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please note that despite start number change, you will still have two separate lists.